# Animating popup display

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml

I'm using a simple storyboard in a Windows Store app to fade in the display of a dynamically created popup. The `storyboard` target is the popup, and the code is:

```
popup -> IsOpen = true;      
Storyboard^ storyboard = dynamic_cast<Storyboard^>(Resources -> Lookup("fadeIn"));
storyboard->Begin();
```

This works, but since it's not clear to me how much the popup and the storyboard know about each other, I was wondering if there was any situation in which the popup might display before the story board starts. For example, does it depend on a UI cycle time with the popup waiting to open at the start of the next cycle, and if the storyboard starts in the same cycle the fade in will happen, otherwise not?

Answer (score 0):

That is fine. When UI begin to render, it will check "IsOpen", if is open, show it. Then Begin fade in.